# Is it a virus on my PC?

Tags: sql-server, ftp, anti-virus, virus, command-line

Somehow sqlservr.exe launches cmd.exe (with very strange command line params) and ftp.exe processes on my PC, please see screenshots. I have already installed antivirus. What it could be, how to treat or fix that?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That tends to look like you've been compromised ("pwn3d"). That's pretty suspicious activity. I'd get that box off the 'net as quickly as you can, start investigating how the breach might have occurred, and be ready to restore the machine from backup if something persistent has been installed on the box.

There may not be anything persistent installed on your machine (yet). I tend to think there isn't.

It's likely that you've got [`xp_cmdshell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) enabled in your SQL Server instance and a remote attacker is using that functionality in an attempt to bring down code and execute it on your box. Based on the fact that `cmd.exe` is being spawned from `sqlservr.exe` this seems likely.

If you know you don't need the `xp_cmdshell` functionality enabled for any application you're hosting I'd go ahead and [disable it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693(v=SQL.105).aspx) (those instructions discuss enabling it, but disabling it can be done with the same process using "0" to disable instead of "1" to enable).

It looks like you might be blocking outbound FTP from the server (bravo!) and that's likely preventing the attacker from bringing down their code and running it.

SQL Profiler can show you the queries the attacker is running to cause the `xp_cmdshell` to be run. Presumably they're injecting SQL into an application that's using SQL Server.

Comment: I concur. Those command-lines are pulling executable content from Out There for local execution.

Comment: The anti-malware program should have reported one of the seemingly many minor variants on the [Trojan-Downloader:BAT.FTP](http://f-secure.com./v-descs/bat_ftp.shtml) theme.